# Double square bracket

Tags: matrices, brackets

I need to have 2 square bracket matrix on the same equation line. I'm able to do just for a single square bracket matrix (for `\xi`) with below

```
 \xi = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
    \xi^1  \\
    \vdots \\
    \xi^L    
       \end{array} \right]
```

[image]

Anyone can give me a hint how to add the second square bracket matrix (for `x`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is very recommended to use `amsmath` whenever one wants to typeset mathematics

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \xi = \begin{bmatrix}
       \xi^1  \\
       \vdots \\
       \xi^L
     \end{bmatrix}
\qquad 
\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
    x^1  \\
    \vdots \\
    x^L    
     \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 \xi = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
    \xi^1  \\
    \vdots \\
    \xi^L    
       \end{array} \right]; 
\qquad
\mathbf{x} = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
    x^1  \\
    \vdots \\
    x^L    
       \end{array} \right] 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```